# Possible numbers of elements in 15 7-sets with pairwise 1-intersection

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $15$ sets, $X_1,\dots,X_{15}$, each one with exactly $7$ elements. We know that $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^{15} X_i= \varnothing$ and $|X_i\cap X_j|=1$ whenever $i\neq j$. Let $n=\displaystyle \left|\bigcup_{i=1}^{15} X_i\right|$.
>
> 1. What are the smallest and greatest values for $n$?
> 2. What are the possible values for $n$? (this one is just for curiosity)

I tried to draw some configurations, but nothing came out of them...

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer. I wrote this down since I guess they are related, and I hope this helps.

You may want to take a look at Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem, which states that with $1 \leq k \leq n/2$, if $F$ is an intersecting family of size $k$ of $[n]=\{1,2,\dots, n\}$, that is, $F=\{F_1,...,F_m\}$ s.t. $F_i \cap F_j \neq \varnothing$ and each $|F_i|=k$, we have $|F| \leq  {n-1\choose k-1}$.

Also if we have $\cap F_i=\varnothing$, then $|F| \leq k^2 {n-2 \choose k-2}$.